# laravel ajax login doesn't work.(i used 'php artisan make:auth')

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6XhL.png)* notice: I used 'php artisan make:auth'
I want to make ajax login. but if i type id and password it show me just error message on the white space.

ex. 1) when i type correct id and password. it return 'true' on the white screen.
    2) when i type incorrect id and password. it return '{"error":{"email":"This is invalide id."}}' on the white screen.

I want to show error in login page. but they don't come back to login page. please help me.

## login.blade.php

```
@php($set = [
    'page' => 'login',
    'title' => '로그인',
    'locate' => '로그인'
])

@extends('m.layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="area_login">
        <img src="images/m/icon_logo.png" alt="" class="img_top">
        @if($status = Session::get('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-info">
                {{$status}}
            </div>
        @endif

        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <div class="shape_input_text">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="이메일" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <div class="shape_input_text">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="비밀번호" required>
                </div>

                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help">
                        비밀번호가 틀렸거나 존재하지 않는 아이디입니다.
                    </span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn_login">이메일로 로그인</button>

            {{-- 비밀번호 기억여부
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>--}}

            <div class="box_links" id="box_links">
                <a class="btn_func btn_find" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    비밀번호찾기
                </a>
                <span class="hyphen">/</span>
                <a class="btn_func btn_register" href="/register">회원가입</a>
            </div>

            <div class="box_easy_login">
                <p class="title">간편 로그인</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn_func btn_facebook">페이스북 로그인</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn_func btn_naver">네이버 로그인</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn_func btn_google">구글 로그인</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn_func btn_kakao">카카오 로그인</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    @section('script')
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".btn_login").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
                    var email = $("input[name='email']").val();
                    var password = $("input[name='password']").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/login",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: {_token:_token, email:email, password:password},
                        success: function(data) {
                            if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                                alert('welcome!');
                                /*location.href="http://localhost:8888/";*/
                            }else{
                                printErrorMsg(data.error);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                function printErrorMsg (msg) {
                    // 1. 이전 에러메세지를 비운다.
                    $(".error").text('');

                    // 2. 에러 메세지를 띄운다.
                    $.each(msg,function(key,value){
                        $(".error_"+key).text(value);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    @endsection
@endsection
```

## LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
            $this->throttleKey($request), 10
        );
    }

    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: "true";
    }

    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json($errors, 422);
        }
        return response()->json(['error'=>$errors]);
        /*return json_encode($errors);*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest adding span with class name error_email where you want to display the error and on the printErrorMsg() change
    $(".error_"+key).text(value); 
    to
    $(".error_"+key).html(value);

Answer (score 0):

thank you, but before that, even i input correct data, don't alert 'welcome'. just print true(i added picture).

## in login.blade.php

$.ajax({
     url: "/login",
     type:'POST',
     data: {_token:_token, email:email, password:password},
     success: function(data) {
        if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
              alert('welcome!');
              /*location.href="http://localhost:8888/";*/
         }else{
               printErrorMsg(data.error);
         }
     }});